# Possible to use tkinter GUI in Jupyter server?

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I have a tkinter script that I usually use in the terminal and it runs fine. However, I want to be able to put it on Jupyter server, so that my non-technical customers don't have to have Python on their computer to use the GUI.

I've been trying to do this but I keep getting the common display error. But I don't have any admin rights to this Jupyter server, so I'm not sure I can change any settings or anything.

Does this mean its not possible for me to use tkinter in this scenario? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about you use something like PyInstaller to bundle all of your project's dependencies into an executable and distribute it that way?

Comment: @user10987432 i've tried that before but the executable was just so slow....and sometimes the computer's security requirements don't allow for executables, which is another pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `tkinter` in this situation. For a python/tkinter application to work, the people who want to run it need to have Python.

Since your users can interact with a Jupyter server, it is probably better to deploy your script as a Jupyter notebook. In that case everybody with a relatively recent web browser can use it.

If it is not a good fit for a notebook, then maybe some other kind of web application.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the insight. I'm making up a notebook with some ipywidgets in place of what the tkinter did-- seems like this is my best bet aside from another kind of web app.